# How can I achieve the equivalent of "Slow Cook High" setting on my multicooker?

Tags: slow-cooking

So a deal site popped up for [this KitchenAid multicooker](https://www.kitchenaid.com/pdf/quickstart/KMC4241/KMC4241_Use_And_Care_Guide.pdf).

I've been meaning to get a slow cooker for a while, and after checking the details of this guy, along with the rest of the stuff it does, I went for it.

Today, I was planning on putting some pork in for 6 hours, on "Slow Cook - High", but the only option was "Slow Cook - Low". I'm not sure exactly what's wrong, but with the other settings of the thing, I think I should be able to achieve just about the same from another setting, specifically the Manual mode,

[image: https://i.imgur.com/Dkn7pRQ.png]

So my question is, to you slow cooking maestros, what setting should I be using to have "Slow Cook - High" equivalence?

([This pork roast](https://www.mynaturalfamily.com/recipes/paleo-recipes/paleo-crock-pot-pork-roast-recipe/) is the recipe I'm trying to try)

Comment: A point worth adding is that slow-cooker manuals usually say pork joints should only be cooked on high. The lack of clarity on the slow cooking options speed me buying such a multi cooker to replace my old slow cooker recently

Comment: "The lack of clarity on the slow cooking options speed me buying such a multi cooker to replace my old slow cooker recently" - sorry, I don't understand what you mean here?

Comment: I'm used to Low and High  modes on a slow cooker. I was thinking of getting a multicooker that claimed to do slow cooking, but gave no further detail.  I looked up the specifications. Counting the modes meant there was only one slow cooking mode, but I couldn't tell whether it was equivalent to high or low, so I bought a slow cooker instead.  her emay be a valid option starting on a different mode and turning down to low after some time, but I don;t know enough to answer that and it may even vary between makes.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the table you've added, your "Low" is not far off a slow-cooker on high. It's just short of boiling but bubbles a bit from the hottest parts. You appear to be able to override the temperature upwards a little anyway.  Slow cookers are based on power input rather than temperature control and expect the ambient temperature to be that of a typical room.  I pointed my IR  thermometer at mine after a few hours of cooking; the outside of the crockpot a few minutes after I removed it from the outer unit was at around 90°C.  Unfortunately this was just out of curiosity and I didn't keep notes.

What's still not clear is where that temperature is measured -- if it's the temperature of the air surrounding an inner pot, the food will take a very long time to reach that temperature.  In that case you should probably start at a higher temperature for a little while.  The recipe book for your cooker may have more details.

Comment: Similar devices (eg, rice cookers) have a part that springs up in the base, just in the middle of the cooking vessel.  The spring is to make sure it makes good contact with the vessel, as that's where the temperature probe is.

Comment: @Joe, yes, I used to have one. The lack of clarity about things like that and how much control I'd have put me off buying a multi cooker when I needed a new slow cooker and would have liked a new rice cooker. I was wary of spending a lot more on something that did everything badly